# Is there a workaround for the Outlook for Mac calendar permissions bug?

Tags: ms-office, calendar, permission

As discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202962/outlook-2016-shared-calendar-doesnt-show-appointments) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2876443/user-with-free-busy-permission-can-t-open-another-calendar-in-outlook), Outlook for Mac users cannot load any other Outlook user's calendar if the latter user's permissions are set to show "Free/Busy Only"; they can only load Outlook calendars whose permissions have been set to "Reviewer" (which I believe allows the viewer to see the event details).

This is really stupid, because (a) Outlook for Windows and Outlook Web Access users can load calendars with "Free/Busy Only" permissions without a problem, and (b) Outlook for Mac users can view other people's availability (at the free/busy level) by using the Meeting Scheduler tool. But this is a bad workaround because (a) it requires several non-intuitive steps in which you pretend to request a meeting and then cancel the invite, and (b) the Meeting Scheduler tool's graphical interface presents the invitee's calendar in a single one-dimensional line format that is almost unusable for looking over multiple days or weeks.

Is there a better workaround? The issue isn't that the viewer needs any additional availability information; they have all the information they need via the Meeting Scheduler, but it's presented in a virtually unreadable format. Is there some simple way to reshape that free/busy availability data into a readable 2D calendar format, as Outlook for Windows users can?

Comment: Those links you supplied have the answer from MS themselves.  It's up to the application developer to provide support for a specific feature or function.  Regardless if you feel it is stupid or not, you need to direct your question to MS.

Comment: @fsb I'm wondering if anyone has developed a workaround - if Microsoft had developed an official fix, then they would presumably have described it on the support page I linked to.